# How to get all corners of path?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a SVG path.

How to get all extremum points from this path? (points of corners)?

I have tried to get all points using this:

```
 let totalLength = path.getTotalLength();

 for (var i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) {
    let point = path.getPointAtLength(i);
 }
```

For exmaple from this Path I need to get coordinates of 4 points, because it is rectangle:

```
<path id="f0" d="M1.825,-11.000 1.825,-363.650 710.925,-363.650 710.925,-11.000z"></path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getPointAtLength()` method gets any point along an `SVGGeometryElement` regardless of if it's a corner or not. There isn't a built-in SVG method for just getting corners.

However, the corners are defined in the `d` path attribute. You could parse them from that, so long as the path only uses absolute coordinates and not relative ones:

```js
const coordinates = document
  .getElementById('f0')
  .getAttribute('d')
  .split(' ')
  .map(pair => pair
    .split(',')
    .map(n => parseFloat(n.replace(/[A-z]/g,'')))
  )
  
console.log(coordinates)
```

```html
<svg>
  <path id="f0" d="M1.825,-11.000 1.825,-363.650 710.925,-363.650 710.925,-11.000z"></path>
<svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is brillian answer for me

Comment: So, then I can draw circle by these coordinates?

Comment: Just be aware that this solution will only work on a small subset of possible paths.  Your paths must (1) only use `M` or `L` commands (2) use absolute coordinates (3) always use commas in the coordinate pairs.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more complete answer ...

```js
const PathCommands = (function()
  {
  const
    regSplit    = /([\+\-.0-9]+)|\s*[\s,]\s*/
  , isLowerCase = str => /^[a-z]*$/.test(str)
  , codPath = 
    { M : [ 'x', 'y']
    , L : [ 'x', 'y']
    , H : [ 'x' ]
    , V : [ 'y' ]
    , Z : []
    , C : [ 'x1','y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x', 'y' ]
    , S : [ 'x2', 'y2', 'x', 'y' ]
    , Q : [ 'x1', 'y1', 'x', 'y' ]
    , T : [ 'x', 'y']
    , A : [ 'rX', 'rY', 'rotation', 'arc', 'sweep', 'x', 'y' ]
    };
  return function(pathStr)
    {
    let
      res     = [] 
    , arr     = pathStr.split(regSplit).filter(Boolean)
    , relativ = false
      ;
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;)
      {
      let cmd = isNaN(arr[i]) ? arr[i++] : relativ ? 'l' : 'L'
      relativ = isLowerCase(cmd)
      res.push( codPath[cmd.toUpperCase()].reduce((a,c)=>{a[c]=Number(arr[i++]);return a},{cmd}))
      }
    return res
    }
  })()
  
// test : 
const pathData = document.querySelector('svg path').getAttributeNS(null,'d')

let drawCommands =  PathCommands(pathData)  

drawCommands.forEach((dc,i)=>console.log(i,JSON.stringify(dc)))
```

```css
svg {
  background : whitesmoke;
  margin     : 1em;
  }
path {
  fill            : none;
  stroke          : blue;
  stroke-width    : 4;
  stroke-linecap  : round;
  stroke-linejoin : round;
  }
  
/** test part **/
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:40% !important; width:60%; overflow: scroll !important;  }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="-40 -390 800 400">
  <path d="M1.825,-11.000 1.825,-363.650 
          710.925,-363.650 710.925,-11.000z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use [SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

see also : https://caniuse.com/?search=getBBox

```js
const yPath = document.querySelector('svg path')

console.log( yPath.getBBox() )
```

```css
svg {
   background: #8ed5e7;
   margin    : 1em;
  }
path { 
  fill            : none;
  stroke          : red;
  stroke-width    : 4;
  stroke-linecap  : round;
  stroke-linejoin : round;
  }
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="-40 -390 800 400">
  <path d="M1.825,-11.000 1.825,-363.650 
          710.925,-363.650 710.925,-11.000z" />
</svg>
```

> **adding a cicle around :**

```js
const 
  svgNS   = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
, pBox    = document.querySelector('svg path').getBBox()
, w2      = pBox.width / 2
, h2      = pBox.height / 2
, circle  = document.createElementNS( svgNS, 'circle')
  ;
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', w2 + pBox.x)
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', h2 + pBox.y)
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', Math.hypot(w2,h2))

document.querySelector('svg').appendChild(circle)
```

```css
svg {
   background : whitesmoke;
   margin     : 1em;
  }
path { 
  fill            : none;
  stroke          : red;
  stroke-width    : 4;
  stroke-linecap  : round;
  stroke-linejoin : round;
  }
circle {
  fill          : none;
  stroke        : blue;
  stroke-width  : 4;
  }
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="-100 -650 900 900">
  <path d="M1.825,-11.000 1.825,-363.650 
          710.925,-363.650 710.925,-11.000z" />
</svg>
```

> That work **even** if the path is not a rectangle who doesn't have anything perpendicular
> it works in all cases, even with curves whose bumps extend the surface of the rectange

```js
const 
  svgNS   = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
, pBox    = document.querySelector('svg path').getBBox()
, rect    = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect')
  ;

console.log( pBox )


rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', pBox.x)
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', pBox.y)
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', pBox.width )
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', pBox.height )

document.querySelector('svg').appendChild(rect)
```

```css
svg {
   background : whitesmoke;
   margin     : 1em;
  }
path { 
  fill            : none;
  stroke          : red;
  stroke-width    : 4;
  stroke-linecap  : round;
  stroke-linejoin : round;
  }
rect {
  fill          : none;
  stroke        : blue;
  stroke-width  : 2;
  }
  
  
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:40% !important; width:60%; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <path d="M25,100 C 25,150 75,150 75,100 S 100,25 150,75" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That only works if the path is both a rectangle and perfectly perpendicular.

Comment: I'm not. You've misunderstood the question. The question asks about "all extremum points from this path (points of corners)" not the bounding box. If it was a hexagon they'd want 6 points.